# OpenAPI Swagger Link on Spring Boot 2 Erroring Not Found when it redirects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I have a spring boot 2 java application with adding the swagger OpenAPI.  I have added the dependency of:

```kotlin
            // Swagger
            "io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:2.2.9",
            "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0",
```

And I have the following class to configure the bean:

```java
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private final ExodusConfig exodusConfig;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param exodusConfig The config
     */
    public SwaggerConfig(ExodusConfig exodusConfig) {
        this.exodusConfig = exodusConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Create Open API bean for use
     *
     * @return The created bean
     */
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenApi() {
        ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger = setDefaults();
        OpenAPI openApi = Optional.ofNullable(swagger)
                .filter(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp::isEnabled)
                .map(this::buildOpenApi)
                .orElse(null);
        return openApi;
    }

    /**
     * Build the contact object
     *
     * @param swagger The swagger config data
     *
     * @return The create object
     */
    private static Contact buildContactObject(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger) {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setName(swagger.getContactName());
        contact.setEmail(swagger.getContactEmail());
        contact.setUrl(swagger.getContacturl());
        return contact;
    }

    /**
     * Build description
     *
     * @param swagger The swagger config data
     *
     * @return The description string
     */
    private static String buildDescription(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger) {
        return swagger.getApm() + " : " + swagger.getDescription();
    }

    /**
     * Build external docs
     *
     * @param swagger The swagger config data
     *
     * @return The created docs
     */
    private static ExternalDocumentation buildExternalDocs(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger) {
        return (new ExternalDocumentation())
                .description("Confluence Documentation")
                .url(swagger.getConfluencePage());
    }

    /**
     * Build license
     *
     * @param swagger The swagger config data
     *
     * @return The created license
     */
    private static License buildLicense(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger) {
        return (new License())
                .name(swagger.getPorttype() + " : " + swagger.getServicekey())
                .url("http://springdoc.org");
    }

    /**
     * Build Title
     *
     * @param swagger The swagger config data
     *
     * @return The title string
     */
    private static String buildTitle(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger) {
        return swagger.getVendor() + " : " + swagger.getName();
    }

    /**
     * Build version
     *
     * @param swagger The swagger config data
     *
     * @return The version
     */
    private static String buildVersion(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger) {
        return swagger.getVersion();
    }

    /**
     * Build components of the api
     *
     * @return The components
     */
    private Components buildComponents(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger) {
        Components securitySchemaType = new Components();
        if (!swagger.getAuthorizationType().equalsIgnoreCase("BEARER")) {
            securitySchemaType.addSecuritySchemes(swagger.getAuthorizationType() + "-Token",
                    (new SecurityScheme())
                            .type(SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
                            .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
                            .name("Authorization"));
        } else {
            securitySchemaType.addSecuritySchemes("Bearer-Token",
                    (new SecurityScheme())
                            .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                            .scheme("bearer")
                            .bearerFormat("JWT"));
        }
        return securitySchemaType;
    }

    /**
     * Build the open api object
     *
     * @param swagger The swagger config data
     *
     * @return The created api
     */
    private OpenAPI buildOpenApi(ExodusConfigSwaggerApp swagger) {
        OpenAPI openAPI;
        openAPI = new OpenAPI();
        openAPI.info((new Info())
                .title(buildTitle(swagger))
                .description(buildDescription(swagger))
                .version(buildVersion(swagger))
                .contact(buildContactObject(swagger))
                .license(buildLicense(swagger)));
        openAPI.externalDocs(buildExternalDocs(swagger));
        openAPI.components(buildComponents(swagger));
        return openAPI;
    }

    /**
     * Get the Swagger app info with defaults if not populated
     *
     * @return The swagger app
     */
    private ExodusConfigSwaggerApp setDefaults() {
        ExodusConfig config = Optional.ofNullable(exodusConfig).orElse(new ExodusConfig());
        ExodusConfigSwagger swagger = Optional.of(config).map(ExodusConfig::getSwagger).orElse(new ExodusConfigSwagger());
        ExodusConfigSwaggerApp app = Optional.of(swagger).map(ExodusConfigSwagger::getApp).orElse(new ExodusConfigSwaggerApp());
        app.setName(setOrDefault(app.getName(), "default"));
        app.setVersion(setOrDefault(app.getVersion(), "unknown"));
        app.setApm(setOrDefault(app.getApm(), "unknown"));
        app.setPorttype(setOrDefault(app.getPorttype(), "unknown"));
        app.setServicekey(setOrDefault(app.getServicekey(), "unknown"));
        app.setDescription(setOrDefault(app.getDescription(), "default"));
        app.setVendor(setOrDefault(app.getVendor(), "default"));
        app.setContactEmail(setOrDefault(app.getContactEmail(), "default"));
        app.setContactName(setOrDefault(app.getContactName(), "default"));
        app.setContacturl(setOrDefault(app.getContacturl(), "default"));
        app.setConfluencePage(setOrDefault(app.getConfluencePage(), "default"));
        app.setAuthorizationType(setOrDefault(app.getAuthorizationType(), "Bearer"));
        return app;
    }

    /**
     * Set the string if it has value to value or else default
     *
     * @param value        The value to set if not blank
     * @param defaultValue The default
     *
     * @return The value if not empty or default
     */
    private String setOrDefault(String value, String defaultValue) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(value)
                .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                .orElse(defaultValue);
    }

}
```

And while I can understand if this is overkill on the break outs.  The problem is when I try to go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html
```

I see it redirects to:

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
```

But then I get the following:

```
{"timestamp":"2023-09-13T17:02:04.695+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/swagger-ui/index.html"}
```

And I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: 1. I see there is some security config. Have you opened all swagger endpoints, e.g. /v3/api-docs/swagger-config as is your example? 2. In my app I only use org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui dependency. You sure you need swagger-models dependency? 3. Try to get rid of your additional configuration. Just let basic swagger to start working to begin with.

Comment: Removing all security did not fix the issue.

Comment: Not sure how to "open" the endpoints as I thought that essentially you just need to create the bean and its code does the rest.